# Adicionando ícone no css

Tags: html, css3, twitter-bootstrap

Estou fazendo um site no trabalho onde precisei fazer um carrousel com o bootstrap, com um estilo "ver mais" ao clicar para abrir o card e o botão virando "ver menos", os jeitos que eu achei bugavam o botão se você clicasse muito rápido, virando ver mais antes mesmo dele fechar. A solução que achei foi usar o before com content e o aria-expanded, assim:

```
.Produtos .container_produtos .conteudo .card #botao[aria-expanded="false"]:before{
    content:" Ver mais ";
  }
  
.Produtos .container_produtos .conteudo .card #botao[aria-expanded="true"]:before{
    content:" Ver menos ";
  }
```

Na frente do ver mais existe um ícone de +, e quando o card abrir, o cliente gostaria que virasse um -, existe uma forma de transformar um ícone usando o before? ou que use o aria expanded para que não bugue

Comment: Que tal `" + Ver mais "` :D, Cara sem seu código não da para te ajudar muito, coloca ai o componente do Bootstrap que vc está usando e diga qual versão do Bootstrap que é.

Comment: Eu usaria javascript para fzr isso. E uma maneira muito boa de usar esses icones é a font awesome, pois os icones são escolhidos de acordo com a classe daquele elemento: https://fontawesome.com
Para alterar a classe vc precisaria apenas usar a proprieda .toggleClass do jquery

Answer (score 0):

Consegui achar uma solução só com css. Achei uma forma de fazer o ver mais e ver menos mudar junto com o ícone, mas ele desconfigurava a fonte do texto por estar somente dentro do content do before, então juntei o after e before e deu certo, muda o texto e ícone do card sem bugar com sucesso.

```
.Produtos .container_produtos .conteudo .card .botao[aria-expanded="false"]:after{
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f055";
    font-weight: 900;
}
.Produtos .container_produtos .conteudo .card .botao[aria-expanded="false"]:before{
    content: "Ver mais";
}

.Produtos .container_produtos .conteudo .card .botao[aria-expanded="true"]:after{
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f056";
    font-weight: 900;
}
.Produtos .container_produtos .conteudo .card .botao[aria-expanded="true"]:before{
    content: "Ver menos"
}
```